# VHDL Array from own entity

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, hdl, vivado

is it possible to declare an array containing own entities?

I'm trying to get 16 registers (4 bit address) and wanted to access them using an array. I have a "register" entity and a register-manager entity, that is accessed by the ALU with the address:

Register:

```
entity register is
    port(en    : in STD_LOGIC; 
         d_in  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0); 
         d_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0));
end register;
```

Register-Manager:

```
entity register_manager is
    port(en   : in STD_LOGIC; 
         addr : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0); 
         data : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0));
end register_manager;
```

**How would I instantiate an array containing these register?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use **for generate** like this :

```
type t_array is array (0 to 15) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal data_array : t_array;

...

process(clk)
begin

  if rising_edge(clk) then

    for I in 0 to 15 loop
      if to_integer(unsigned(addr)) = I then
        data_array(I)  <= data;
      end if;
    end loop;

  end if;

end process;

for I in 0 to 15 generate

  -- Synthetizer will instantiate 16 registers and each will have a different d_in
  inst_register : register
  port map
  (
    en    => en,
    clk   => clk,
    d_in  => data_array(I), 
    d_out => open           -- Your register_manager has no ouput
  );

end generate;
```

*Note :* I introduced a clock because a register without clock in synchronous logic is a bit weird, you should add a reset too. Forgot this note if you are doing some asynchronous logic.